# How to use AuthContext inside of a class component?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks

I have an `auth-context.js` file that looks like this following:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

const AuthProvider = (props) => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  const login = () => {
    setLoggedIn(true);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setLoggedIn(false);
  };

  const authContextValue = {
    login,
    loggedIn,
    logout,
  };
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={authContextValue} {...props} />;
};

const useAuth = () => React.useContext(AuthContext);

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };
```

I am trying to use this to set up authorization, but I am unable to get it to work because this is a function and I need to use it in a class component.

This is how I tried using it in the class component:

```
import { useAuth } from "../auth-context";

// the below is used when a user clicks login
const { login } = useAuth();
login();
```

This is the error I get:

```
Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

So how can I use `AuthContext`? Does it need to be converted to a class component or something else?

This is my `index.js` file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And my `App.js`file:

```
function App() {
  const { loggedIn } = useAuth();
  console.log("Is Logged in: " + loggedIn);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
        <HeaderComponent />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
          <Route path="/" element={<LandingPage />}></Route>
        </Routes>
        <FooterComponent />
      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 - create a new component that wraps the `Login` component, and use [`Context.Consumer`](https://MyClassComponent), and pass the context values via the props:

```
const WrappedLogin = () => (    
  <AuthContext.Consumer>
    {authProps => <Login {...authProps} />}
  </AuthContext.Consumer>
)
```

In the `auth-context.js` file export `AuthContext` as well, so you can import it:

```
export { AuthProvider, useAuth, AuthContext };
```

Option 2 - create a new component that wraps the `Login` component, and use `useAuth` to get props, and pass them to the `Login` component:

```
const WrappedLogin = () => {
  const authProps = useAuth();

  return <Login {...authProps} />
}
```

With options 1 & 2, you'll get the `AuthContext` values via the props:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn } = this.props;
  }
}
```

Option 3 - If this is the only context that the component is going to consume, you can use [`contextType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype). In this case you can consume your `AuthContext` values via `this.context`:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn } = this.context;
  }
}
Login.contextType = AuthContext;
```

In the `auth-context.js` file export `AuthContext` as well, so you can import it:

```
export { AuthProvider, useAuth, AuthContext };
```

Comment: Im not sure I follow. I updated the question with more of my code. I am using `<AuthProvider>` to wrap my components.

Comment: Export `AuthContext` as well and wrap your class component with the provider, or use the AuthContext` as `contextType`.

Comment: Which one is the class component?

Comment: My class component is a `Login` component. I click the button login, and I need to change `loggedIn` to `true`

Comment: So in my `Login` component, after I import `AuthContext`, how can I access `loggedIn`?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Go over the examples.

Comment: If I use option 3, can I change the value of the context?

Comment: Remember to render `WrappedLogin` in the `Route` instead of `Login` if you use options 1 or 2.

Comment: What do you mean by the `value`?